# write a program in java to return the list of the subsets of a given array with the help of backtracking and recursion without using loops

Tags: java, recursive-backtracking

```
import java.util.ArrayList;`
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> list= new ArrayList<>();
        int[] arr = {2,3,5};
      subset(list,nums,arr,0);
        System.out.println(list);
    } 
static void subset(List<List<Integer>> list,ArrayList<Integer> nums,int[] arr, int index){
        if(index==arr.length){
          list.add(nums);
            return  ;
    }
        int c= arr[index];
        nums.add(c);
      subset(list,nums,arr,index+1);
        nums.remove(nums.size()-1);
       subset(list,nums,arr, index+1);
   return ;
    }
}`type here
```

output={[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}
expected={[2,3,5],[2,3],[2,5],[2],[3,5],[3],[5],[]}
can anyone tell me why it is giving empty list ?

I wrote a program for returning a list containing lists of subsets of a given array  using backtracking and recursion , I called a function named subset of void returntype where I was adding elements ie, subsets in the list (containing subsets of a set) and expecting to then print that list  after coming out of the function but it is giving me list  of empty lists ie, {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]} , can anyone please help me solving this problem.

Comment: Try stepping through your code with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

When you add `nums` to `list` using `list.add(nums)`, you are actually adding a reference to the `nums` ArrayList. This means that when you modify `nums` later on by adding or removing elements, those changes will also be reflected in the subsets already added to `list`. As a result, all subsets in `list` end up being the same, which is an empty list at the end of your recursion.

To fix that, you need to create a new ArrayList and add a copy of `nums` to `list` instead of adding the reference directly. This way, each subset in `list` will be independent of the changes made to `nums` afterwards.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] arr = {2, 3, 5};
        subset(list, nums, arr, 0);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    static void subset(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> nums, int[] arr, int index) {
        if (index == arr.length) {
            list.add(new ArrayList<>(nums)); // Add a copy of nums to list
            return;
        }

        int c = arr[index];
        nums.add(c);
        subset(list, nums, arr, index + 1);
        nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
        subset(list, nums, arr, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 5], [2, 3], [2, 5], [2], [3, 5], [3], [5], []]
```